# Move commits from one PC to another to push to Git Repository

Tags: git

I've got an home-office related problem due to current corona crisis. I'm working on an app on MacBook but cannot access the Git repository from there. To access the git server, I have to use my Windows Notebook which is in corporate VPN and therefore can reach the git server.

**So my question is:**
What is the best way to transfer the changes from MacBook to Windows Notebook and to push the changes to the git repository from Windows Notebook?

The project is quite big, so I would like to avoid always transferring the whole project.

Comment: How can you share data between the two machines? Can you at least connect a USB stick to both?

Comment: Why can't you install the VPN software on your MacBook and clone the repo normally? Why can't you work on your Windows notebook? In general, it's useful to explain why the obvious, simple answer isn't an option up front, otherwise you're going to get people asking why you aren't doing the simple, obvious things.

Comment: @choroba yes i can

Comment: You can create a new "remote" on the USB stick and use it from the both machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For code files, you could generate patches using `git diff` (see documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-generate-patch)). You could then copy the patches to the Notebook, apply them to the local repository, then commit and push to the remote as usual. If you have binary resources, then just copy them across.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @RadioSilence for the [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60971428/10098485).

So, with `git diff > patchfile.diff` the patchfile will contain all changes since the last commit.

If you have commited your changes already, you can use

```
git diff from-commit to-commit > output-file
```

for example, if you want the changes to your previous commit

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD > patchfile.diff
```

then you would copy the patchfile to the other system, apply the changes and commit

```
git apply patchfile.diff

git add .
git commit -m "git diff works"
git push
```